# How to make a function call via pointer-to-member-function to a templated function?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, language-lawyer, pointer-to-member

I tried to compile the following code.

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    T fun()
    {
        std::cout<<"CALLED!"<<std::endl;
        return T();
    }
};

class Derived : public Base 
{ 

};

template<class T>
T (Derived::*func_ptr)() = &Base::fun;

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    ///how to call?
}
```

To my surprise, this compiled in both clang and gcc. This gives me the idea that somehow we should be able to call `fun` by `func_ptr`. However, I cannot think of what the syntax should be to call the function by this pointer. What is the syntax for it and how is it explained?

Also another thing is, I cannot think of a reason for this to compile. Where is this behavior defined in C++ standard?

Comment: compiles, but undefined behavior, because `fun` is missing a `return`

Comment: _I cannot think of what the syntax should be to call the function by this pointer._ If you don't know how to use pointers-to-members or how to pass arguments to templates, read some C++ intro book.

Comment: The syntax for calling a pointer-to-member is `(o.*f)()`. In this case, the object is `d` and the function pointer is `func_ptr<T>` for some type `T`. There's nothing particularly ambiguous or language-lawyery about this.

Comment: Whatever book you're using to learn C++ did you a disservice when it told you how to declare a pointer to a member function, but not how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, I cannot think of what the syntax should be to call the function by this pointer. What is the syntax for it?

```
(d.*func_ptr<int>)();  // or other template argument
```

> How is it explained? Where is this behavior defined in C++ standard?

`func_ptr` is a variable template. There are very few rules in the Standard specifically about variable templates, but they are allowed in C++17 and later by [[temp.pre]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.pre) paragraphs 1 and 2.

In your definition

```
template<class T>
T (Derived::*func_ptr)() = &Base::fun;
```

the expression `&Base::fun` is a pointer to overloaded function, as described in [[over.over]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/over.over). When each specialization of the `func_ptr` template is instantiated, it has a specific pointer-to-function type `T (*)()` as the target, and the correct template argument for `Base::fun<T>` can be deduced from that.

To use a variable template, template arguments must be provided. (Template argument deduction can only happen for function templates and class templates.)  So `func_ptr<int>` is an expression of type `int (*)()`. Then that's combined with the syntax `(obj.*mem)(args)` for
calling a pointer to member function.